# ¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para definir un arreglo multidimensional que se usa en toda la aplicación?

Tags: c++, diseño

Debo realizar un mini proyecto que permita controlar las reservas de un evento.

Nota: El evento se realizará en un estadio de dos pisos, el cual tiene a su vez cuatro lugares donde un cliente se puede ubicar (SUR,piso1 y piso2), (NORTE,piso1 y piso2), (ORIENTE piso1 y piso2), (OCCIDENTE.piso1 y piso2).

Lo que no me deja realizar este proyecto es que no se cómo, ni dónde ubicar el arreglo para que me quede bien estructurado.

Comment: ¿cuál arreglo no sabes donde ubicar?

Answer (score 3):

No tomes esta respuesta como una norma ya que generalmente no se responden a preguntas que no incluyan código. Respondo a tu pregunta porque la declaración que pides, por si misma, no sirve para terminar el ejercicio.

**Declarar el arreglo**

Te están diciendo que el piso tiene dos plantas y cada planta 4 habitaciones. Con esto te están describiendo una matriz de 2x4. Si asumimos que en cada posición de esa matriz tienes pensado almacenar valores enteros una posible definición sería:

```
int matriz[2][4];
```

Otra posibilidad, ya que hablas de C++, es hacer uso de la clase `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::array<int,4>,2> matriz;
```

Su sintaxis es un poco más compleja pero el resultado es prácticamente el mismo. ¿Por qué usar entonces `std::array`? Al ser una clase te va a proporcionar una serie de facilidades a la hora de manipular sus valores, como iteradores, información sobre sus dimensiones, etc.

**¿Dónde declararla?**

Lo ideal sería dentro del `main` y pasarla como parámetro a aquellas funciones que lo requiriesen.

**¿Y no sería más cómodo declararla como estática?**

Las variables estáticas son muy rápidas de declarar y, aparentemente, muy fáciles de usar. También es muy sencillo apretar el acelerador del coche a tope pero eso no quiere decir que necesariamente vaya a ser una buena opción. Las variables estáticas tienen el problema de que al ser accesibles desde cualquier parte del código es muy sencillo perder la noción de quién está accediendo a la misma en cada momento, lo que propicia que aparezcan errores bastante complicados de encontrar.

**¿Necesito memoria dinámica?**

En el caso que presentas en el que el tamaño es conocido de antemano no es necesario hacer uso de memoria dinámica, por lo que puedes evitar hacer uso de `malloc` y `free` o `new` y `delete`.

Si tienes más dudas me temo que tendrás que editar tu pregunta y aportar más información.

Comment: Gracias creo que con esto puedo realizarlo!

Answer (score 0):

Te daré las indicaciones principales, y en base a eso deberías desarrollar el resto.

En C/C++ hay varias maneras de definir un array uni o multidimensional, una de las más basicas es la siguiente

```
int matriz[cantidad_filas][cantidad_columnas];
```

En el ejemplo anterior te he definido un array o arreglo bi-dimensional, conocido también como matriz, dado que tiene dos dimensiones ("alto" y "largo"), como las matrices matemáticas.

Así mismo, esa matriz que definí permite guardar números enteros (por el tipo de datos usados), pero fácilmente puedes usar otros tipos (primitivos del lenguaje, o definidos por el usuario).

```
float matriz_reales[cantidad_filas] //un array unidimensional de reales
double matriz_super_reales[cantidad_filas][cantidad_columnas][cantidad_fondo] //un arreglo tridimensional de reales de doble precisión
char crucigrama[10][100] //una matriz de caracteres, que podrías usar por ejemplo para un crucigrama
```

**Nota:** *por supuesto, se asume que las variables para indicar la cantidad de filas, columnas, etc... ya están definidas, y que son de tipo Entero, si usas otro tipo te dará un warning o error*

En el caso que propones, sería algo así (en realidad no sé con exactitud que deseas guardar la matriz, así que asumiré que quieres guardar la cantidad de personas que ya han reservado en determinada locación y piso)

```
int reservas[2][4];
reservas[0][0]; //primer piso, locación norte
reservas[0][1]; //primer piso, locación sur
reservas[0][2]; //primer piso, locación este
reservas[0][3]; //primer piso, locación oeste
reservas[1][0]; //primer piso, locación norte
reservas[1][1]; //primer piso, locación sur
reservas[1][2]; //primer piso, locación este
reservas[1][3]; //primer piso, locación oeste
```

Puedes cambiar el significado de las filas y las columnas a conveniencia.

Por supuesto, este es un tema más extenso, y lo mejor sería que investigaras mas al respecto y luego vengas con dudas mas especificas.

Comment: El problema de OP no es solo sobre cómo declarar un arreglo, también el **dónde**

Comment: No leí la edición.

Una respuesta podría ser ubicarlo como una variable global, pero no es una buena práctica.

La otra es que lo pase convenientemente como parámetro en las funciones que vaya a usar.

Answer (score 0):

Parece un trabajo para...

#### El especificador [`extern`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Este especificador aplicado sobre un identificador indica que su enlazado es externo, esto significa:

> El nombre puede ser referido desde los contextos de otras [unidades de traducción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Las variables y funciones con enlazado externo también tienen enlazado entre lenguajes, esto hace posible enlazar unidades de traducción escritas en otros lenguajes de programación.

#### Vamos a verlo con un ejemplo.

Suponiendo este `main.cpp`:

```
#include "archivo1.hpp"
#include "archivo2.hpp"

extern int matriz[2][4];

int main()
{
    imprime_1();
    matriz[0][0] = 111;
    matriz[0][1] = 222;
    matriz[0][2] = 333;
    matriz[0][3] = 444;
    imprime_2();
    return 0;
}
```

Tenemos un arreglo de dos dimensiones llamado `matriz` y dos funciones llamadas `imprime_1` e `imprime_2` las cuales están declaradas y definidas en los siguientes archivos:

```
// archivo1.hpp
void imprime_1();
```

```
// archivo2.hpp
void imprime_2();
```

```
// archivo1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "archivo1.hpp"

extern int matriz[2][4];

void imprime_1()
{
    for (const auto &x : matriz)
        for (const auto &y : x)
            std::cout << y << '\t';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

```
// archivo2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "archivo2.hpp"

extern int matriz[2][4];

void imprime_2()
{
    for (const auto &x : matriz)
        for (const auto &y : x)
            std::cout << y << '\t';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Vemos que cada uno de los archivos de código (`*.cpp`) hacen referencia al arreglo `matriz` como elemento externo, al ejecutar el programa vemos lo siguiente:

> ```
> 1         2         3         4        5        6        7        8    
> 111       222       333       444      5        6        7        8
> ```

Caramba, ¿de dónde salen esos datos? ¿dónde está definido el arreglo `matriz`?. El arreglo lo hemos declarado como externo en `main.cpp`, `archivo1.cpp` y `archivo2.cpp`... pero no he añadido este otro archivo:

```
// matriz.cpp
int matriz[2][4] =
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
};
```

Este es el único lugar en que el arreglo `matriz` está declarado, y carece del especificador `extern`.

Es decir: para usar una variable `extern` debe estar declarada como `extern` en todos los lugares en que se use y definida sin `extern` **en un único sitio**. El compilador se encargará de enlazar todas las declaraciones en los archivos de código (unidades de traducción) con la definición con el mismo nombre y tipo.

Puedes ver el [ejemplo funcionando aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/waWMJXiskf8giSAI).

#### Conclusión.

Una de tus preocupaciones es...

> dónde ubicar el arreglo para que me quede bien estructurado.

Con la propuesta que presento, puedes ubicar el arreglo en un solo sitio: por ejemplo su propio archivo de código; esto (en mi opinión) te deja una buena estructura de código.